# What is this winged seed that resembles Maple/Acer?

Tags: identification, seeds, seedlings

I picked up these seeds on the streets of Marrakech in Morocco (I've found similar seeds in Lisboa, Portugal), thinking they were Maple/Acer seeds. Upon germination (which took an awful lot of time) it turned out they weren't Acer at all. What are they? Scale is in cm.

[image: Not-Acer seeds and their seedlings]

Comment: That doesn't look like a sterilized mix. Could be different seeds that sprouted first.

Comment: Could you dig near the roots, to see it the seedling grow from the winged seed?

Comment: I left Morocco and Portugal half a year ago, so the above is all I can provide. At that time I was certain they were Maple seeds, so I didn't even consider looking for alternative sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be Tipuana tipu - its a South American tree, a member of the Fabaceae or legume family, widely planted in warmer regions of the world. Scroll down this link, under 'Helicopters (whirlibirds)': - [Blowing In The Wind - Seeds & Fruits Dispersed By Wind](http://waynesword.palomar.edu/plfeb99.htm).

Comment: I went to same conclusion (it seemed more a Fabaceae), but the form seems still more Acer, and it is not so frequent in mediteranean (AFAIK)

Comment: I agree, it certainly looks like Tipuana tipu, both the seeds and the leaves. If nobody has any objections, I will mark this as a valid answer.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I agree. Fabaceae 100%. This is not an Acer seedling but the seeds most definitely are.

Comment: @Brenn uh? Tipuana does produce samaras like these, even though they could be Acer seeds going from appearance alone

Comment: My bad. You're right. On my phone, I didn't see that this seed terminated in a funicle as opposed to another samara. I now agree that it's Tipuana, a genus I was not immediately familiar with.

Comment: Well you're not alone - it was only luck I chose the right phrase to do a search, I knew nothing about Tipuana myself. Quite interesting it produces samaras because they really do look like Acer seeds...

Comment: @Brenn the seeds you see is what gave me the seedling, so both are Tipuana.

Comment: Yup @Klaus Alexander Seistrup, I agreed once I inspected the image closer. See? ^^

Comment: You're quite right, @Brenn, I missed that.